# Python3 seems more expensive with google app engine than python2

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-app-engine, migration, gcloud

We had our application, on App Engine standard environment, GEN1 , developed on runtime, python 2.7 and webapp2 framework, deployed on google app engine.

Currently, we're in the migration process to update our framework from Webapp2 to flask and effectively, we're updating our python runtime as well, from python27 to python 310.

We've migrated the code base, however, we're facing some unexpected issues:

- With webapp2, the google app engine build size raised upto 140 -160 MB, but when after migration to flask, python 310, the size rose upto, 480-500 MB..
- Upon debugging, we found out, it's the same size that the project is engulfing locally on the machine.. i mean did webapp2 apply compression while deploying of app engine? And Flask isn't applying such compression?
- Now, for all my F1 instance class declared, the build is deployed successfully, but my front end does not load, it's because my build size is about 480MB, greater than that of the F1 memory limit i.e 384 MB in the second gen runtime for the App engine standard environment.
- We did few experiments to evaluate this build size rise i.e we checked adding requirements.txt in .gcloudignore that reduced size to 200 MB, and moreover, adding static folder, further reduced 136 MB. I mean we cannot add these in the .gcloudignore as these are required.

Also for example, if i go live with such build size, if i have 20 instances let's suppose, on an F2 instance, when will it spin another instance, using automatic scaling, and in return have an affect on billing
Moreover, i did refer this question asked on forum i.e [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Migrated-to-py3-and-Appengine-is-much-more-expensive-Am-I-doing/m-p/680336), but did not prove fruitful.

Comment: Have a look at this [similar issue](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Migrated-to-py3-and-Appengine-is-much-more-expensive-Am-I-doing/m-p/680336).

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I did go over this issue, but there was a missing .gcloudignore file that was causing big build size in that case.

Comment: You can add your concern over there.

Comment: See my [response](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Migrated-to-py3-and-Appengine-is-much-more-expensive-Am-I-doing/m-p/681325/highlight/true#M2792) to your post on Google Cloud Forum

Comment: You must provide details to get a good answer, otherwise, we are just guessing. Start by creating a minimal reproducible example for both Python 2 and Python 3. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SaadRafique, Can you edit your post by sharing minimal reproducible examples as John asked?